# Having problems with reading on android make files

Tags: android

I'm fairly new to this.

I was currently handed a project. I built the android code for android 4.2.2_r1
I was then told to read up on android make file and to understand it.

Naturally I googled that. But there's scarce introductory information.

What IS the android make file? Can someone give me a run down or a resource to check out?

Answer (score 1):

The generic idea of Make is, it is an tool that automatically builds executable programs and libraries from source code by reading files called makefiles which specify how to derive the target program.

[image]

The Android.mk file defines the native sources you want to compile and then build executable .apk file.

To go deep, start from here: http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html

Answer (score 1):

The material in the [NDK makefile docs](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/text/ANDROID-MK.text) is a good place to start.  Beyond that, I'd say pick a project, look at its `Android.mk`, and try to figure out what everything in it does.

Just bear in mind that *all* `Android.mk` files involved in the build are gathered up at once and processed as one large makefile -- Android does not use recursive invocations of `make`.